# Error while importing SQLObject on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sqlobject

I am getting following error while importing SQLObject on Window. Does anyone knows what is this error about and how to solve it?

==============================

```
    from sqlobject import *
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from main import *
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    import dbconnection
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\dbconnection.py", line 17, in <module>
    from joins import sorter
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\joins.py", line 5, in <module>
    import events
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\events.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlobject.include.pydispatch import dispatcher
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg\sqlobject\include\pydispatch\dispatcher.py", line 30, in <module>
    import saferef, robustapply, errors
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `c:\python26\lib\site-packages\sqlobject-0.10.4-py2.6.egg` file may be truncated or otherwise damaged. How does it compare to a freshly downloaded one (in terms of both length and checksum)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check that.